# Prove that a particle is traveling on a plane from its velocity and acceleration in space

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

We have a particle that travels in 3d space. It is given that $a(t)=-r(t)$.

First I need to prove that: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\underline r \times \underline v)=0$$ This is easily done:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\underline r \times \underline v)=r(t) \times r''(t)+r'(t) \times r'(t)=0
$$
Then I need to prove that the vector $\underline r \times \underline v$ is a constant. This leads immediately from the previous fact:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\underline r \times \underline v)=0 \Rightarrow \int \frac{d}{dt}(\underline r \times \underline v)dt=0 \cdot t+C=C.
$$
Then I need to prove that $\underline r \times \underline v$ is perpendicular to $\underline r$:
$$
\vec{r}\cdot (r \times v)=v(r\times r)=v \cdot0=0
$$

From this I need:

1) to prove that the particle is moving on a plane

2) find on which plane and with what normal vector.

3) find a point that the particle passes

For this I made this sketch:
[image]
My guess is that:

1) normal vector is $r\times v$ which is $\overrightarrow{BD}$ in the picture.

2) The plane is defined by the normal vector and any point on the curve.

3) the particle definitely passes through the origin $(0,0,0)$.

Yet this doesn't really make sense because one could think that every particle always travels on the same plane.

Comment: A particle doesn't have to obey the law of $\frac{d}{dt} (\vec{r} \times \vec{v}) =0$ , this happens only sometimes. Do you have any more facts given in the question that you didn't show us? Because if not, your proof is invalid.

Comment: @OfekGillon there're no additional facts given. This is from a calculus course I suppose we're not interested in the problem from the physical perspective. It does say that $a(t)=-r(t)$ but I assume this is a general truth.

Comment: That is an important detail, why would it be a general truth? take for example $r(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$ then $a(t)=(0,2,6t)\neq -r(t)$. Almost any given $r(t)$ won't satisfy the equation you just wrote

Comment: @OfekGillon I thought it always holds. Added the detail to the post. thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. Another thing, can you explain this part in your proof? 
$\vec{r}\cdot (\vec{r} \times \vec{v}) = \vec{v} \cdot (\vec{r} \times \vec{r})$

Comment: @OfekGillon this is an identity that was taught to us.

Comment: Ok, just making sure you're aware of the identity and not just guessing that it is a valid one :) . I will now answer your question fully in the answers section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll define for convenience $\vec{r}\times \vec{v}$ as $\vec{L}$

You proved that $\frac{dL}{dt}=0$ and hence $\vec{L}$ is constant.

That means there is a constant vector which is always perpendicular to $\vec{v}$, and that means the motion is restricted to a plane ($L$ is the vector perpendicular to the plane). That answers too the normal vector part in question (b).

So your guesses were correct but you thought that every particle has the property of $r(t) = -a(t)$, which is only right for a particle attached to a spring.

Comment: So the normal vector is $\overrightarrow L$ right? And the the particle has to pass through the origin?

Comment: No, for $r(t)=(\cos t , -\sin t , 0)$ this doesn't happen

Comment: I thought that $a=-r$ always because in our book they say that because $F=ma$ then $a$ and $r$ have opposite directions. Then they say that $r \times a=0$

Comment: So when they ask about a point that the particle passes through, what point do they mean?

Comment: Do you have any initial values for the position and velocity?

Comment: No I don't have any other details

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing anything that looks trivial?

Comment: After clarifying the problem details with our teacher, I need to say through which point the plane goes through

Comment: OK, now I can say that the answer is the origin. Here is an explanation:
Suppose $L = (L_x , L_y , L_z)$ and $r=(x,y,z)$ , then we know that $L_x x + L_y y + L_z z = 0$ because $\vec{L} \cdot \vec{r} = 0$. Here I defined a plane that passes through the origin (substituting $x=y=z=0$ solves the equation) and the motion is restricted to it (because $L$ is constant)

Comment: $L$ is the normal vector to $r$. The scalar product of any vector and its normal vector is $0$. Does this mean that every plane goes through $0$?

Comment: Also what if $r=(0,5,0)$ and $L=(5,0,5)$?

Comment: Yos, you can try and check that if a particle is moving on a plane that doesn't go through the origin, $L$ isn't conserved :)

Comment: What is "conserved"? Do all planes pass through origin?

Comment: Constant with respect to time. For example, conservation of energy means that energy is constant in time

Comment: Or are you saying that if $(0,0,0)$ solves $L \cdot r$ then the plane passes through origin? We can also find infinitely many more points then right? (permutations of a zero within three coordinates with all numbers)