# Why does a plane with normal constant vector pass through the origin?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Given a vector $r=\langle r_1,r_2,r_3\rangle$ it is known that $n=\langle n_1,n_2, n_3\rangle$, a vector perpendicular to it, is constant. It transpires that the plane which contains the vector $r$ passes through the origin.

The proof given for this is that $r\cdot n=0 \Rightarrow r_1n_1+r_2n_2+r_3n_3=0$ and $x=y=z=0$ satisfies the equation.

Why does this prove that the plane passes through the origin?

Is $r\cdot n$ the plane equation?

Doesn't any plane that go through the origin by that logic?

This answer was given in the comments to the answer of this question: [Prove that a particle is traveling on a plane from its velocity and acceleration in space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255959/prove-that-a-particle-is-traveling-on-a-plane-from-its-velocity-and-acceleration)

This is the visualization:
[image]

Here the plane is drawn to pass through origin but I could've drawn it to pass through any other point for example.

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$ at the end the explanation is quite simple: any vector is defined to start at the origin. Because the position vector travels on a plane and its normal vector is constant then, the motion has to start at the origin. If someone wants to post an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: $r\cdot n=0$ is the equation of a plane through the origin. $r\cdot n=1$ is not.

Comment: @Semiclassical Just trying to understand this: for a plane equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ to hold we need a point and a normal vector. We have the latter but does $r$ provide the point? Doesn't it provide just the direction?

Comment: $r$ is a position vector, so it's tip lies on the plane. Thus, $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ is a point on the plane.

Comment: @wgrenard ok so by that logic can't we say that any plane goes through origin because any plane has a vector and a normal vector to it?

Comment: Every line or vector perpendicular to the plane's normal vector is parallel to the plane. If the plane does not pass through the origin, the vector from the origin to a point in the plane meets the plane at some non-zero angle. The position vector is not parallel to the plane, so it cannot be perpendicular to the plane's normal vector.

Comment: Conversely, if you know that there is some point in the plane whose position vector _is_ perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane, the origin cannot be off the plane, so it must be on the plane.

Comment: @DavidK if we have a particle that travels on a plane. Its $r$ vectors belong to the plane. And they're always perpendicular to the normal vector. But such planes can be anywhere in 3d space why can't the plane be parallel to $z$ axis for example?

Comment: Your last comment is simply false. For example: the plane $z=2,$ normal vector $n=\langle 0,0,1\rangle$. One point in the plane is $(x,y,z)=(0,0,2),$ and its position vector is $r=\langle 0,0,2\rangle$ which is _not perpendicular_ to $n=\langle 0,0,1\rangle$ (in fact it is parallel).

Comment: In my understanding in our case the particle moves on a plane. The directions in which it moves are represented by $r$, there're infinitely many. Because the particle moves on the plane the $r$ vectors are part of the plane (in any vector of form $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $A$ and $B \in$  the plane). So the normal vector to the plane is always perpendicular to the $r$ vectors. For example in my drawing, $r$ travels the curve and eventually passes through point $A$ and throughout its travel the normal vector $\overrightarrow{BD}$ is always parallel to it.

Comment: I am fairly sure your understanding is wrong in this case. The direction of motion is given by a velocity vector. In your other question, it seems clear that the velocity vector is $v$ and the position vector is $r.$ If the particle passes through point $B,$ then at that instant $r = \overrightarrow{OB}$ where $O$ is the origin.

Comment: Is it because any vector is defined to start from origin?

Comment: When you say **the** plane **containing** the vector $r$, it seems that you're thinking of a “plane of vectors”, i.e., a two-dimensional subspace of the vector space $\mathbf{R}^3$, and subspaces always contain the zero vector. But if you think of a “plane of points”, then of course you can translate it in space and still keep $n$ as a vector normal to the plane and $r$ as a vector parallel to the plane. (But in that case you really shouldn't say that $r$ is *contained* in the plane.)

Comment: @HansLundmark this is exactly what I was thinking. The only way this proof makes sense to me is that any position vector is defined to start from the origin. Then because the particle moves on a plane then indeed the plane must go through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The comments give one way of understanding, but I figured I could maybe explain the original proof better.

Suppose our plane has normal vector $n$ (which is normal to the plane at every point on it) and an example point on the plane: $p$. These two vectors, one a direction and the other a point, determine any plane.

Then, our plane equation is $$ n\cdot(x-p)=0 $$

that is, every $x$ that satisfies this equation is a member of the plane. This is equivalent to $n\cdot x = n\cdot p$.
Notice that $x=p$ is a member of the plane. But, $x=p+n$ is not a member, nor is $x=\vec{0}$, assuming $p\ne \vec{0}$.

Another way to write this is as a point set $\Pi$:
$$
\Pi = \{ \;x\in\mathbb{R}^3\;|\;n\cdot x= n\cdot p\;\}
$$
i.e. these are the set of points making up the plane. Again, notice that if $p=\vec{0}$, then the origin is a point in $\Pi$. But if $p$ does not vanish, then the origin is *not* in the plane.

The reason is that $p$ is a translation or shifting parameter. That is, a plane has an orientation parameter, $n$, which "rotates" it, and a position parameter $p$, which slides the plane around. When $p=\vec{0}$, we have slid the plane so that it intersects that origin. The plane equation in this case is $n\cdot x = 0$.

---

Here's a different approach. Every plane is determined by giving 3 unique points. Let's take $p,a,b$. Define $T_1=a-p$ and $T_2=b-p$. We can suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are orthogonal; if they are not, we can use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization.

Now, suppose we walk around between $p$ to $a$ or $b$. This is the same as adding some multiple of $T_1$ or $T_2$ to $p$. So a *parametric equation* for the plane is
$$
x(s,t) = p + sT_1 + tT_2
$$
so that if you input any $s$ and $t$, your output is a point on the plane.
See also [here](http://mathinsight.org/plane_parametrization).
Notice that a normal vector is simply $n=(T_1\times T_2)/||T_1\times T_2||_2$.
So we get equivalence to $n\cdot(x-p)=0$ as before.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation!